Knight tour graph for a board with holes
Using this function to construct a path for knight's tour on a given 6x3 board:
KnightTourGraph[6, 3, VertexSize -> 0.05, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

Which is fine, however I found no Option values for this function to define a board with holes in it.  Say I have an 8x8 board with the 4 corners (of 2x2) taken out, plus the dead center 2x2 also removed. Can we use the same function to get a hamilton path for this?
So 3 items for this:
1-Add holes as above and solve. my-board
Assume we start at the lower-left? (3,1)?
2-The labels shown above go sequentially up and to the right - is there a way to have them number the actual path traveresed instead? For Above: 1-->should be 1,  6-->should be 2,  7-->should be 3 etc
3-This one is just a bonus - given an nxn board, have a function to take in 2 co-ordinates: A(a,b) and B(c,d) then determine what's the shortest way to get from A->B using a knight.

Do you mean like this?:
r = 8;
c = 8;
ktg = KnightTourGraph[c, r, VertexSize -> 0.05, 
   VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[c*r] -> Range[c*r]]];
v = {1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 49, 50, 55, 56, 57, 58, 63, 64, 28, 
   29, 36, 37};
g2 = VertexDelete[ktg, v];
hc = FindHamiltonianCycle[g2];
GraphPlot[HighlightGraph[g2, hc],
 VertexLabels -> 
  MapIndexed[#1 -> First[#2] &, Replace[hc, {cyc_} :> First /@ cyc]],
 VertexCoordinates -> 
  Delete[Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 &, Partition[Range[c*r], r], {2}], 1], 
   List /@ v]]


#3 seems a separate question, and generally SE prefers one question per question, but FindShortestPath[] ought to do it.

Or maybe this is preferable:
g3 = VertexAdd[g2, v];
GraphPlot[HighlightGraph[g3, hc],
 VertexCoordinates -> (First@Position[Partition[Range[c*r], r], #] & /@
     VertexList[g3])]



You can put a chessboard in back with ArrayPlot or MatrixPlot. Style as desired:
Show[
 ArrayPlot[Array[Mod[1+##, 2] &, {8, 8}], PlotRangePadding -> None,
  ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[(2 + #)/3] &)],
 GraphPlot[
  HighlightGraph[g2, hc], 
  VertexLabels -> 
   MapIndexed[#1 -> First[#2] &, 
    Replace[hc, {cyc_} :> First /@ cyc]],
  VertexCoordinates -> 
   Delete[Flatten[
     MapIndexed[#2 - 1/2 &, Partition[Range[c*r], r], {2}], 1], 
    List /@ v]]
 ]



Oops, add VertexLabels ->  MapIndexed[#1 -> First[#2] &, Replace[hc, {cyc_} :> First /@ cyc]] to the g3 plot to get the vertices labeled by order of traversal.

Thanks @Michael E2 : I am supposed to start at the lower left square first! Is there a way to make it go off from there instead of mid left?  (start from position #33 on your first chart)

Also @Michael E2 : when you do the vertex delete, i see you are passing in all the digits. How do those map to the corners and mid? I mean: is the initial 8x8 board numbered from top left...it looks like!

@Steve237 You're welcome. :) (1) Try flipping the coordinates. (I can't see that it makes a difference, mathematically speaking, since it's a symmetry.) Code to try: VertexCoordinates ->  Reverse /@ (First@Position[Partition[Range[c*r], r], #] & /@ VertexList[g3]). (2) You told us which vertices to delete and I deleted them; or rather, put them in the list v of ones to be deleted. Your code shows which ones they are (changing both 6 and 3 to 8), which code I used for ktg above. You even pointed out the numbering that is used in your question, so I'm not sure what's mysterious here.

I guess I made a slight mod to your code for the VertexLabels for ktg.  That prevents automatic relabeling of the vertices when they are deleted, it seems. That's a useful step I should have pointed out, but it slipped my mind til now.

Hi @Michael E2 :  is it a quick fix to change the output to look like a chess board? instead of just vertices

@Steve237 Updated. You could also use Graphics[{Raster[Array[(2. + Mod[+##, 2])/3 &, {8, 8}]]}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None] instead of Array/MatrixPlot.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

n = 8;

holes = Join[Tuples[{1, 2, 7, 8}, 2], Tuples[{4, 5}, 2]];

vlist = Complement[Tuples[Range[n], 2], holes];

relation = Sort @ Abs[# - #2] == {1, 2} &;

vcoords = Thread[vlist -> vlist - Threaded[{1, 1}/2]];

g0 = RelationGraph[relation, vlist, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords];

hc = First @ FindHamiltonianCycle @ g0;

g1 = Graph[RotateLeft[#, -1 + Position[#, {3, 1}][[1, 1]]]& @ VertexList @ hc, 
   DirectedEdge @@@ hc, 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue], VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
   GraphStyle -> "IndexLabeled"];

chessBoard = ArrayPlot[
    ReplacePart[Array[Mod[# + #2, 2] &, {#2, #}], #3 -> Red], 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> GrayLevel[.5]}, ##4, 
    FrameTicks -> All, DataReversed -> True] &;

Show[chessBoard[n, n, holes], g0, g1, ImageSize -> Large]


Update: Shortest paths
spg[s_, t_, color_] /; SubsetQ[VertexList@g0, {s, t}] := 
  PathGraph[FindShortestPath[g0, s, t ], 
   DirectedEdges -> True, 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, color], 
   VertexCoordinates -> vcoords,
   GraphStyle -> "IndexLabeled"];

spg[__] := Graphics[{}]

Multicolumn[
 Show[chessBoard[n, n, holes], g0, spg[##], 
    PlotLabel -> PromptForm[path, {#, #2}], 
    ImageSize -> Medium] & @@@
    {{{3, 3}, {6, 8}, Blue},
     {{2, 3}, {7, 7}, Purple}, 
     {{2, 3}, {7, 4}, Green}, 
     {{2, 3}, {8, 3}, Orange}}, 2, Dividers -> All]



Thanks @kglr !  remember we need to start off at position 33 ! Is there a simple update for that? ....  plus the bonus #3 from my original question!

@Steve237, please see the update.

so (2,3) to (7,7) there is no possible path I take it? ....

Hey did you switch also to start at position 1 in place of where 15  is ...in your first image...Thx!

In the first picture, i changed the start position to {3,3} per your comment above.

Start position should be {3,1}

@Steve237, changed the start position to {3,1}.
